# Finding all sets of elements with two common elements in a large dataset

Tags: performance-tuning, searching, intersection

I have a very large network of atoms ($\approx 10^6$ atoms) with fixed positions that resemble a cellular structure:

[image]

I have two files including:

- fixed locations of each atom
- set of points which makes each cell.

The first one is like:

```
 1 1.72907 3.50783
 2 3.89771 506.561
 3 514.767 4.35252
 ...
```

The second dataset has $\approx 5 \times 10^5$ rows (but size of each row is different). For example:

```
{1,3,485,969,970,971,1452}
{1,487,488,970,972}
{1, 485, 486, 487, 966, 968}
{2,99706,99707,99708,99709,100190,100191}
{2,99225,99226,99227,99708,99710,99711}
{2, 99222, 99223, 99224, 99225, 99706}
...
```

I need to find out all sets which have exactly two elements in common ($=$ two cells share an edge or in other words, are neighbors). I already have a code but it's inefficient because it compares the sets line by line. Here's my code ($n$ is number of rows):

```
 ParallelEvaluate[file = OpenWrite["RN" <> ToString[$KernelID] <> ".dat"]]    

 ParallelDo[
 WriteString[file, i, " ",
 Flatten[Last[Reap[Do[If[Length[Intersection[ring[[i]], ring[[j]]]] == 2, 
 Sow[j]], {j, 1, n}]]]], "\n"]
 , {i, 1, n}];

 ParallelEvaluate[Close@file];
```

I find intersection length of a specific set $i$ (`ring[[i]]`) with all other sets and if it is equal to two, I write the set number in a file. Is there anyway to improve efficiency of this code?

### Update

I have an alternative solution without using `Intersection` and with only one loop, as follows:

```
 ring = ReadList["rings.dat", Number, RecordLists -> True];
 ParallelEvaluate[file = OpenWrite["RN" <> ToString[$KernelID] <> ".dat"]]    

 ParallelDo[
 RN = Complement[First/@Tally[Flatten[First /@ Position[ring, #] & /@ ring[[i]]]],   
 {i}];
 WriteString[file, i, " ", RN ,"\n"]
 , {i, 1, n}];

 ParallelEvaluate[Close@file];
```

But it seems it is not that much better than previous one.

Comment: {i,1,n} loop is thing missing in you code.

Comment: What result do you expect from {{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}}?

Comment: This set has three members, let's call them A,B,C. I want to have: {{A,B},{B,C}}

Comment: You could let the comparison not go twice, i.e., let the iterators go from {j, 1, n}, {i, j + 1, n} (check out Block[{n = 4}, Do[Print[{i, j}], {j, 1, n}, {i, j + 1, n}]] )

Comment: If a set has >2 members in common, it is to be excluded as "special"? In any case, I may have some fast code for this kind of problem, searching library now... Also, are elements exact integers as in your example, and if so, domain limits if any?

Comment: I think you'll need to further specify details to get any useful answer: What is the data (any possibility of doing work *as* the data is generated?). Is there structure to the data (it appears to be sorted in rows, includes consecutive sequences, and perhaps first element is only increasing or staying the same through rows?). How many unique elements? Can there be duplicate elements in a given row? Do you need only indices of rows, or also *what* the match pairs are? Short of info leading to shortcuts, you're at 1.3X10^11 conparisons, 30+ hours even if you could do each in a microsecond.

Comment: @rasher As I mentioned above, I only need to sets that have **exactly** two common elements. About Data: I have $\approx 1 \times 10^6$ atoms on a plane with fixed positions. Data shows the point number. Each atom is connected to three other atoms. So I find that which atoms form a closed loop. In fact, each row is a closed loop with no repetitive element. Rows are sorted by first element. And the only thing I need is index of rows.

Comment: @RolfMertig Thanks, that helps. But the question is if I find that $i$ and $j$ has two common elements then how my code should remember that $j$ has also two common elements with $i$?

Comment: @Mehdi: Ah, "...on a plane with fixed positions...", that's potential for a huge boost: can you scan the plane with an nXn plane that contains just the local atoms that *could* share a loop? In other words, do you have the needed correspondence between atoms and positions to do that?

Comment: @rasher: I have index and location of all atoms in a file but I don't know what you mean by "nXn plane". Honestly, I haven't done any localization before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14837/discussion-between-rasher-and-mehdi).

Comment: I realize there are effective ways to do this. But let me also ask: Is there reason not to treat this as a graph, with nodes as vertices and edges connecting neighbors?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: No there is no reason! Honestly my prefered way is seeing this as a graph. I just thought computations on graph are not fast compared to this kind of computation. Another reason: I'm a newbie at Combinatorica.

Comment: Much of Combinatorica has been redone within the framework of Mathematica's `Graph`. So I'd recomment looking through some of that docuemtation. In your example though, since you know in advance what are the "faces", neighbors are simply faces with a common edge. So all the work would be in associating edges to faces. Probably can be done without too much fuss, is my guess.

Comment: Consider first constructing a connectivity list of cells associated with each atom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apologies for typos I had to retype this.  (edit there was one now fixed)

```
 amax = Max@Flatten@idx;
```

construct complementary connectivity list.

```
 atomc = Flatten@# &/@ Last@Reap[Do[Sow[i,#]&/@idx[[i]],{i,Length[idx]}],Range[amax]];
```

extract neighbors (should be fast):

```
 celln = Flatten@(First/@Select[Tally@Flatten[atomc[[#]]&/@#],#[[2]]==2 &]) &/@idx ;
```

timing results for the example set w/ 823 cells:

> {.0251,.0238}

for the two steps.

example result: `celln[[400]]`

> {397,399,402,744,745}

This takes a minute for ~10^6 cells.

Comment: +1 Nice use of tags in `Sow`

Answer (score 3):

```
idx = Import["c:/bazaar/rings.dat"];Max[Flatten[idx]]
```

gives 1799 distinct points;

```
First /@ Position[idx, 7]
```

shows that point 7 occurs in 'cycles' 5,7 and 8

```
v = Cases[Tally[Flatten@idx[[First /@ Position[idx, 7]]]], {q_, 2} -> q]
```

tells us that, apart from point 7 (occurring 3 times), points 5, 27 and 28 occur twice.
Now, we need to list the results as pairs of pairs:
 cycles {i,j} share points (p,q) or,
{{i,j},{p,q}}, ...

We can do that by:

```
Function[w,v=Cases[Tally[Flatten@(u=idx[[First/@Position[idx,w]]])],{q_,2}->       
 q];Transpose[{Part[v,#]&/@((First/@Position[u,#])&/@v),Sort@Thread[{w,v}]}]
]/@Range[1799]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot but final line doesn't return correct answer.

Comment: the " {q_,2}-> q];Transpose[ " got massacred in copy-paste. Oopsie!

Comment: Oh I used the correct form, but the result is not what I want. But the question has an update now based on what you suggested. It gives intended results and I am happy with that. On my current machine (A core 2 Duo with 4GB ram) for first 100 rings, the original one takes 15 seconds but updated solution takes 9 seconds to do the task.

Comment: must have missed it somewhere, is the test data available? How big is it? Obviously not 10^6 cells..?

Comment: @george2079: I have shared test data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgIi7LSP4luR2xlU2Y5UnhoQ0E/edit?usp=sharing