# saving outputs of loop

Tags: iterators, save

I am stuck on a problem. I have outputs generated at every iteration of a do loop. However, I want to save the outputs in some other file format, like text file etc, in such a way that i must be able to use any output from iteration later. But the more I am searching about it, the more I am getting confused. Please guide in this respect.
Like I read the options 'import', 'export', 'sow', 'reap', 'get' etc but i need simple description. Please guide me in this respect.
I quote the example as
I have some initial

$a$ as $V0 +\Delta V*\Delta t/T$.  Then I update the value of $\Delta t $  by having an increment of value $T/ntmax$  and define $b$ as  $V0 +\Delta V*\Delta t/T$ .  And then I have to multiply both $a$ and $b$ as $Exp[b]*Exp[a]$
I have to repeat this process until $\Delta t $ $/T$ reaches equal to $T$, as shown in the below loop.

```
Do[
 a = V0 + ΔV*Δt/T;
 Δt = Δt + T/ntmax;
 b = V0 + ΔV*Δt/T;
 f = Exp[b]*Exp[a],
 {Δt, T/ntmax, T, T/ntmax}]
```

As during each iteration I will obtain the new value of $f$. I have to plot few values of $f$. However, I want to keep the record of all, so that I may be able to plot any one of them.

Comment: Do[Export["test" <> ToString[i] <> ".txt", i^2], {i, 1, 5}] creates 5 files test1.txt, test2.txt etc each containing a single number 1, 4, 9, etc.

Comment: `Put` is also useful. Your question is very broad though. A more specific question (with examples and preferrably code) will get better answers.

Comment: `in such a way that i must be able to call the output of any iteration step in some other program`  I am having hard time understanding what this mean. May be MWE will help.

Comment: Please use mathematica input form..  For this simple example simply replacing `Do` with `Table` will generate a list of sucessive `f` values.

Comment: further (looking at the answers) you should not be doing file operations inside the loop unless some very good reason (eg loop execution is taking hours, or you are generating huge amounts of data ).  Try to clarify what you really want.

Comment: @george2079: About your above comment, is there any serious thing about including file operation inside the loop? (In case that we don't have large dataset)

Comment: ok i try to explain what i actually want to do. I have divided my total time T into small steps $\Delta t$ .I want to multiply two functions such that   current value of f at some current time= value of f at current time step* value of f at past time step. and i want to repeat it until I reach at some final time T.

Comment: The issue with fileio is just that it will be quite slow compared to saving the data to memory and writing it out all in one shot.

Comment: @zenith Please format inline *Mathematica* code with backticks and not as TeX with dollar signs.  Blocks of code are formatted by indenting four spaces or using the code button just above the edit window, just as I have done for you.  Please fix the rest.

Comment: @george2079: Thank you for info. Actually the reason I asked was that I have a question right now on **StackExchange** that writes a large output into a file. That would be great if you can take a look at: http://alturl.com/uibgi

Comment: @Mehdi You might get more traffic if you posted the original URL, which will show directly that it is linking to *Mathematica*.SE.

Comment: @george2079:  Thanks!http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48839/finding-all-sets-of-elements-with-two-common-elements-in-a-large-dataset/

Comment: Just to make sure - you want to save results across kernel session? Or do you just want to keep the iteration results in a list for later use in the same session? Does your evaluation take very long?

Comment: @YvesKlett I want to keep the iteration results for later use. My evaluation takes lon time as i divide my total time into smaller and smaaler steps.

Comment: @Mehdi , yours is an example where the loop execution time is so long that the file write time is not significant.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do usually to save my result:

```
SetDirectory["Directory"](* Sets your directory to a folder you want*)
file = OpenWrite["file.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm](* Opens a file called file.dat *)
Do[
F[i](* calculates what you like as a function of i *)
Write[file, F[i]]; (* writes F[i] in ith line of the file*)
,{i,1,n}]
Close[file];
```

In your case, you calculate $f=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ at each iteration. Like the above, before closing `Do` loop, write:

```
Write[file,f];
```

I think that is all you need. If you want to plot $f(t)$ versus $t$ later, it is better to write both in the file:

```
Write[file,t," ",f];
```

This command writes $t$ and $f$ of each iteration with a space in between.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what I understood is that in this way I can save the outputs in .dat format. Right? Now how can I use any of these outputs in my Mathematica window, to plot or perform some other operations on it.

Comment: Yes, the result will be in a file named _file.dat_. After you successfully saved everything inside this file, you can use `import` to have an array and then use `ListPlot` (for example).

Comment: this helped to save my data and retrieve while using do loop.  Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're only using hundreds of iterations, then `Table` as [@george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) suggests in a comment is the simplest way to go.  If you're looking at millions of iterations, then using the vectorized property of the built-in functions is more efficient.  Below, 100 million values are computed in a little over 3 seconds (Mac 2.7GHz 16GB i7):

```
V0 = 1.;
ΔV = 2.;
T = 5;
ntmax = 10^8;
data = Evaluate[Simplify[ Exp[V0 + ΔV*#/T] * Exp[V0 + ΔV*(# + T/ntmax)/T] ]] &@
   Range[N@T/ntmax, T, T/ntmax]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3.216403, Null} *)
```

Simplifying this particular expression reduces the computation time to about 1/3 of the time it takes the unsimplified expression.

A smaller example:

```
ntmax = 10;
Exp[V0 + ΔV*#/T] * Exp[V0 + ΔV*(# + T/ntmax)/T] &@
  Range[T/ntmax, T, T/ntmax]
(*
  {13.4637, 20.0855, 29.9641, 44.7012, 66.6863, 99.4843, 148.413, 221.406, 330.3, 492.749}
*)
```

---

If you want to save the result in a file, you can use [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html):

```
DumpSave["data.mx", data]
```

It can be read with [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html).

Comment: great...very elegant approach to solve problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A basic solution, which prints one iteration per line, is

```
(* create a temporary directory and move to it *)
SetDirectory[CreateDirectory[]];
outfile = "results.txt";
(* "touch" outfile *)
Put[outfile];  
Do[
 (* append i to outfile *)
 PutAppend[i, outfile],
 {i, 5}]
FilePrint@outfile
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5